# How to find the general solution to this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to find the general solution to this system of equations using an augmented matrix, and then using the gauss reduction technique, but i cant seem to get it into row echelon form no matter what i try.
The system is:

```
4w - 5x - y + 21z = 17
-w + 3x + 4y - 2z = -2 
w - 2x - 2y + 4z = 3 
3w - 8x - 8y + 6z = 11
```

I have tried everything i can think of, but i cant seem to figure it out.
If someone could please give me some pointers i would be immensely grateful.

Thanks in advance
Timothy

Answer (score 3):

The following should be manageable enough for you to follow (note that you need to obtain the **reduced** echelon form of the system of equations in order to determine the general solution):
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}4&-5&-1&21&17\\-1&3&4&-2&-2\\1&-2&-2&4&3\\3&-8&-8&6&11\end{bmatrix}&\sim \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-2&4&3\\-1&3&4&-2&-2\\4&-5&-1&21&17\\3&-8&-8&6&11\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
&\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-2&4&3\\0&1&2&2&1\\0&3&7&5&5\\0&-2&-2&-6&2\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
&\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-2&4&3\\0&1&2&2&1\\0&0&1&-1&2\\0&0&2&-2&4\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
&\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-2&4&3\\0&1&2&2&1\\0&0&1&-1&2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
&\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0&2&7\\0&1&0&4&-3\\0&0&1&-1&2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
&\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&10&1\\0&1&0&4&-3\\0&0&1&-1&2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\[1em]
\end{align}
Thus, your general solution is given by
\begin{cases}
w &= 1-10z\\
x &= -3-4z\\
y &= 2+z\\
z & \text{is free}
\end{cases}